# How to remove duplicate values in a List <ExpAdminBean>?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

I check my case I have a listing where a process after the data is loaded with this information:

```
-> ExpAdminBean [codTipoExpediente=1, desTipoExpediente=Exp Coactivo, siNumSecuencia=2, nroDocumento=null]
-> ExpAdminBean [codTipoExpediente=19, desTipoExpediente=R Sancion, siNumSecuencia=0, nroDocumento=218-056-02742669]
-> ExpAdminBean [codTipoExpediente=2, desTipoExpediente=Rec, siNumSecuencia=0, nroDocumento=220-041-01169690]
-> ExpAdminBean [codTipoExpediente=19, desTipoExpediente=R Sancion, siNumSecuencia=0, nroDocumento=218-056-03048986]
-> ExpAdminBean [codTipoExpediente=2, desTipoExpediente=Rec, siNumSecuencia=0, nroDocumento=220-041-01169690]
-> ExpAdminBean [codTipoExpediente=23, desTipoExpediente=CIR, siNumSecuencia=0, nroDocumento=218-174-00146216]
-> ExpAdminBean [codTipoExpediente=2, desTipoExpediente=Rec, siNumSecuencia=0, nroDocumento=220-041-01169690]
```

What I have to do to eliminate duplicate records but the **nroDocumento** attribute, the attribute **nroDocumento** not be repeated, if any should be removed repeated, I wanted to use a Hash Set, but also is present as null, which complicates little.

My code Java:

```
Map<String, Set<ExpAdminBean>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<ExpAdminBean>>();   
Set<ExpAdminBean> setExpAdmin = null;
for(ExpAdminBean exp : listaExpAdminAux) {
    setExpAdmin = new HashSet<ExpAdminBean>();      
    map.put(exp.getNroDocumento(), setExpAdmin);                
}           

List<String> listExp = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for(String keySist : map.keySet()){                  
    listExp.add(keySist);
}
```

Comment: Does `ExpAdminBean` already implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`?

Comment: Hello friend, it's true that I can implement and official, but that would apply when there is exactly the same record, my case is that the nroDocumento attribute is not duplicated in ExpAdminBean class.

Comment: Uh, you do not have to implement them on _all_ fields. My question is whether you had done it or not, or you don't want to do it and are looking for an alternate solution -- in which case Guava has the solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collection without duplicates (how to determine duplicates being up to you) is a `Set`.
A collection that **maintain** an arbitrary order is a List (in ArrayList the default order is the order of insertion). Note that list MAINTAIN an order ... but does not necessarily sort its elements.

Anyway if you want to keep the insertion order AND keep out duplicates you can use a `LinkedHashSet<>`.

In your case you need to reimplement the `equals(~)` and `hashCode()` functions of your ExpAdminBean class if possible. I suggest you implement it so that equals returns true when nroDocumento is equal and return the hashCode of nroDocumento dirrectly in the new hashCode implementation.

Otherwize if you cannot do that I suggest you use a map:

```
Map<String, ExpAdminBean> map = ~~~~~~ ;
for(ExpAdminBean exp : listaExpAdminAux) {
    if(!map.containsKey(exp.getNroDocumento())
        map.put(exp.getNroDocumento(), exp);                
} 
//if you need to put the values in a list you can do ...
ArrayList<ExpAdminBean> theList = new ArrayList<>(map.size());
theList.addAll(map.values());
```

Like I said before if you want to keep the "insertion order" of your first list you should use a `LinkedHashMap<>` or a `LinkedHashSet<>`.